# Como extiendo el model User de django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Quiero crear algo como un blog de estudio, pero quiero crear un usuario que posea mas atributos de los que trae por defecto el auth_user de django, leí que se puede extender esta clase y vi un ejemplo mas o menos asi:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Usuario(models.Model):
        usuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
        fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
        sexo = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

no se si me explico, y disculpen mi ignorancia empece en django hace 3 dias, y este es mi primer proyecto en este framework.

Comment: cual es tu duda ? como lo tienes plateado esta bien, es así como se suele hacer

Comment: Lo estás haciendo bien de ese modo. Hay varias formas de hacer eso, pero con tu implementación debería alcanzar. Usar modelos relacionados puede implicar un mayor número de consultas y joins para recuperar la información relacionada (penalizar el rendimiento), pero sugiero que no te preocupes por eso ahora, salvo que estés haciendo algo con demanda masiva. Para más detalles te sugiero que le des un vistazo a la documentación oficial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay Tres Formas de Extender el modelo de usuario

La primera es con un **OneToOne** (tal como lo estas haciendo)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Alumni(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cinta = models.CharField(max_length=100)
# Create your models here.
```

La segunda Forma es utilizando **AbstractUser** por ejemplo:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    cinta = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Esta agrega mas campos al modelo de usuario que trae por deafult django

Por ultima esta la forma de rehacer todo el modelo de usuarios de Django por ejemplo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password,
                     is_active, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('El email debe ser obligatorio')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_active=is_active,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(
            email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(
            email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, models.Model):
    # unique, no se van a repetir
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    apaterno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    amaterno = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    numero_celular = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    genero = models.CharField(
        choices=(('M', 'Mujer'), ('H', 'Hombre')), max_length=16, blank=True)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    # intermediario entre trans de cada modelo, object managaer de cada modelo
    objects = UserManager()

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Las dos ultimas formas necesecitan ser agregadas en el **settings.py** como:

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "Nombre_de_la_app.Nombre_del_modelo"

Espero esta Informacion te sirva en el futuro ;)